# How to convert some WPF event handler to EventHandler<E>?

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling, callback, weak-references

I use the article [here](http://diditwith.net/2007/03/23/SolvingTheProblemWithEventsWeakEventHandlers.aspx) to implement the weak referenced handler pattern.

The code is really perfect before I found that the event handler in WPF is not the instance of EventHandler. Such as `PropertyChangedEventHandler`:

```cs
public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
```

Although I think they have the same signature as `EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs>`, where `EventHandler` is :

```cs
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

I try to convert it directly but the C# said "I cannot do it".
So my question is it possible to smoothly convert these two kind of delegate?
What's the different between them?

Answer (score 0):

I have some delegates with type parameters, and I convert them like this:

```
    public void AddHandler(EventHandlerUntyped<TKey> EventHandlerMethod)
    {
        SomeEventTakingTypedEventHandler += new TypedEventHandler<TKey, TValue>(EventHandlerMethod);
    }
```

These are the delegates:

```
public delegate void TypedEventHandler<TKey, TValue>(object sender, TypedEventArgs<TKey, TValue> ItemInfo);
public delegate void EventHandlerUntyped<TKey>(object sender, EventArgsUntyped<TKey> ItemInfo);
```

PS: The Typed Event Args inherits the untyped event args.

I know it's not exactly what you want, but I think it's a good hint.
You can ignore the `TKey` and try something like:

```
   new EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(SomeMethodUsingPropertyChangedEventHandlerSignature).
   new PropertyChangedEventHandler(SomeMethodUsingCommonEventHandlerSignature);
```